# How is Navigation from ContentDialog to a different page in UWP which uses Template10 MVVM possible?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp-xaml, template10, navigationservice

**LoginPageCD.xaml**

```
<ContentDialog
x:Class="ScanWorx.ContentDialogs.LoginPageCD"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ScanWorx.ContentDialogs"
xmlns:vm="using:ScanWorx.ViewModels"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Name="LoginPageContentD"
SecondaryButtonText="close"
SecondaryButtonClick="LoginPageContentD_SecondaryButtonClick">

<ContentDialog.Resources>
    <Thickness x:Key="ContentDialogPadding">16,16,16,16</Thickness>
    <vm:LoginPageCDViewModel x:Key="CDViewModel"  />
</ContentDialog.Resources>

<!--  Content Dialog Title  -->
<ContentDialog.TitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >

        <TextBlock
            HEADER DATA FOR TEMPLATE/>

    </DataTemplate>
</ContentDialog.TitleTemplate>

<ContentControl x:Name="LoginPageContentControl" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="500" Height="500">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <ComboBox
                    x:Name="Combobox_Login_test"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Header="Combobox_Login.Header"
                    IsEditable="True"
                    ItemsSource = "{Binding UserNameList, Source = {StaticResource CDViewModel}}" 
                    Text="{Binding Name, Source = {StaticResource CDViewModel},FallbackValue=DesigntimeValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                <PasswordBox
                    x:Name="PasswordBox_Login"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Header="PasswordBox_Login.Header"
                    Password="{Binding Passwort, Mode=TwoWay , Source= {StaticResource CDViewModel}}" />

                <Button
                    x:Name="Button_Login_Click"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Command="{Binding LoginButtonCommand, Mode=TwoWay, Source= {StaticResource CDViewModel}}"
                    Style="{ThemeResource AccentButtonStyle}"/>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

**LoginPageCD.xaml.cs** <== *Code behind*

```
using ScanWorx.ViewModels;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources;
using Template10.Mvvm;

namespace ScanWorx.ContentDialogs
{

public partial class LoginPageCD : ContentDialog
{

    public LoginPResult Result { get; set; }

    public static ResourceLoader dict;
    public LoginPageCD()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ViewModelBase viewModelBase = new LoginPageCDViewModel();
        this.DataContext = viewModelBase;
        dict = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("Login");
        LoginPageCDViewModel LPVM = new LoginPageCDViewModel();
        LPVM.UpdateUserNameList();
    }


    private void LoginPageContentD_SecondaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        rootFrame = new Frame();
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Views.LoginPage));

        LoginPageContentD.Hide();
       
    }

}
}
```

**LoginPageCDViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using Template10.Mvvm;
using Template10.Services.NavigationService;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Template10.Utils;

namespace ScanWorx.ViewModels
{
class LoginPageCDViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public static ObservableCollection<string> _UserNameList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> UserNameList { get { return _UserNameList; } set { Set(ref _UserNameList, value); } }

    private string _Name = "";
    private string _Passwort = "";

    public RelayCommand LoginButtonCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public string Name { get { return _Name; } set { Set(ref _Name, value); } }
    public string Passwort { get { return _Passwort; } set { Set(ref _Passwort, value); } }


    public static ResourceLoader dict;

    public ObservableCollection<string> UpdateUserNameList()
    {
        try
        {
            **A FUNCTION TO UPDATE THE USER's LIST IN THE COMBOBOX**
            **USAGE: USED IN CODE BEHIND WHILE INITIALIZING THE CONTENT DIALOG**
        }
        catch
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Catch Exeption:  LoginPage.xaml.cs     Invalid UserManagement.xml file");
        }
        return _UserNameList;
    }

    public LoginPageCDViewModel()
    {
        if (Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
        {
            Value = "Designtime value";
        }
        Services.SettingsServices.SettingsService.Instance.IsFullScreen = true;

        LoginButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(Button_Login_Click, () => true);

        dict = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("Login");
    }
 
    public async void Button_Login_Click()
    {
        try
        {
                **ACTION: some code to check the username and password**

                loginPageCDViewModel.navigatetomain();        //<<<<// a function to navigate to main page which doesnt work     
                //NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.MainPage));

        }
        catch
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Catch Exeption:  LoginPageCDViewModel.cs     Button_Login_Click");
        }
    }

    public void navigatetomain()
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        rootFrame = new Frame();
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Views.MainPage));
        LoginPageContentD.Hide();

        //NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.MainPage));

    }
}
}
```

- The above work is what I have tried. I also tried to navigate to the main page using `NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.MainPage));` but it is also not working.
- Any help is appreciated
- I am able to navigate to mainpage using the function `navigatetomain()` but the content dialog doesnt close even though i am trying to `Hide();` and also after navigation I am not able to see my hamburger menu in my Mainpage its just a blank mainpage.

**NOTE:** The `Hide();` in code behind for close button works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a button of my own [Button_Login_click] I used the primarybuttonclick of contentdialog and using relaycommand declared in `LoginPageCDViewModel.cs` I Binded the primarybuttoncommand property to the relaycommand button declared in `LoginPageCDViewModel.cs`

So now my LoginPageCD.xaml looks like

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="ScanWorx.ContentDialogs.LoginPageCD"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ScanWorx.ContentDialogs"
    xmlns:vm="using:ScanWorx.ViewModels"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="LoginPageContentD"
    PrimaryButtonCommand="{x:Bind Path=vm:LoginPageViewModel.LoginButtonCommand }"
    PrimaryButtonText="Login"
    SecondaryButtonText="close"
    SecondaryButtonClick="LoginPageContentD_SecondaryButtonClick">
   .
   .
   .
```

and for navigation to the desired page I am making use of the result of the contentdialog box i.e I am calling the `ShowAsync();` at the start of the app and after recognizing the primary click I am using `NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.MainPage));` to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at your code, but it looks like it commented out some content. Here are some of my thoughts:

1. Keep the uniqueness of ViewModel

I noticed that you created 3 `LoginPageCDViewModel` in ContentDialog related code, namely `ContentDialog.Resources`, `viewModelBase` and `LPVM`.

This may cause confusion, you can try to create only a `LoginPageCDViewModel` and set it as `DataContext`, which can be bound in XAML.

2. Unknown reference to `LoginPageContentD`

When you try to close the ContentDialog, the code used is `LoginPageContentD.Hide()`. But I did not find the definition of this variable in the code you provided.

Does it refer to the current ContentDialog? You can use debug breakpoints to track the code to see if the reference is normal.

- If it is called inside ContentDialog, you can directly use `this.Hide()`.
- If this is a variable that represents the current ContentDialog instance, then it should be assigned a value when ContentDialog is started, like:

```cs
public LoginPageCD()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ViewModelBase viewModelBase = new LoginPageCDViewModel();
    this.DataContext = viewModelBase;
    dict = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("Login");
    viewModelBase.UpdateUserNameList();

    viewModelBase.LoginPageContentD = this;
}
```

If the above suggestions can't solve your problem, can you provide a minimum runnable demo (does not contain private information, but can run and reproduce the problem) so that we can test and analyze the cause?

Comment: Okay, so yeah my query is difficult to understand sorry since i cant post the entire code so iapologize. the thing is I have a loginPage (not talking about the posted LoginPageCD) which is having two buttons. one for calling out the contentdialog(LoginPageCD) and one is internal initialization purpose(this button is not related to login). so once login button is pressed content dialog is opened on which i have a combobox and passwrd box and login button and a close button

Comment: So, basically the click function of button to open content dialog is binded in the viewmodel of loginPage and the function `navigatetomain()` is written in loginPageViewModel.cs and not LoginPageCDViewModel.cs since an instance of LoginPageCD is created in loginPageViewModel.cs because after pressing the button on loginPage i have to show the contentdialog

Comment: what about the navigation can you tell what am i missing to navigate to the proper page with the hamburger menu not missing ?

Comment: Hello, I don’t know if our Template Studio configuration is the same (I’m Navigation Pane + MVVM Light). If we're same, please make sure your page is registered in `ViewModelLocator.cs` before navigating. If you want to keep the hamburger menu (you may be means `ShellPage.xaml`), then you need to call the `NavigationService` in `ShellViewModel.cs `to navigate, instead of creating a `NavigationService` yourself